# How to get ASP.NET MVC authorize attribute work with users in nested AD groups?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Does ASP.NET MVC authorize attribute work with nested AD groups?
In the FilterConfig.cs file, I have the below line

```
filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute() { Roles = @"AD.COM\IT" });
```

However, if AD.COM\user is in a nested group ITApps inside IT AD group, it doesn't work. How do I get it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the AD group name had space at the end. Once I removed that, it seems to work fine.